# Can we create videos of different sizes in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to create videos of different sizes with AWS Lambda function. Is it possible to create videos in different size ? From where i get the documentation for this. ?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda allows you to run code without any servers. What you run in a Lambda function is totally under your own control.

Lambda itself does not have video processing features, but a Lambda function could call the [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html) service to convert videos.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have to use Amazon Elastic Transcoder, I want to do it custom with nodeJs . Can i do it with custom nodeJs. ?

Comment: AWS Lambda function can run node.js. However, there is a 5-minute limit on Lambda functions and a limit of 500MB of temp disk space. If you have node code that can do your desired work within those limits, then that's fine.